# POST request from Python to PHP

Tags: php, python, arrays, url, urllib

Python

```
 params = urllib.parse.urlencode({'spam': '1', 'eggs': '2', 'bacon': '3'})
    binary_data = params.encode('utf-8')

    reg = urllib.request.Request("http://www.abc.com/abc/smart/ap/request/",binary_data)
    reg.add_header('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
    f = urllib.request.urlopen(reg)
    print(f.read())
```

PHP

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {  
//parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
var_dump($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}
```

When i try print binary_data , it does show the parameter but by the time it reaches the PHP , i see nothing.

Any idea?

Edit**

I just did more test, if i do a

```
urllib.request.Request("http://www.abc.com/abc/smart/ap/request/?item='test'",binary_data)
the parameter, item , does get sent to php.
```

Comment: fix the indentation of your code

Comment: how are you sure it's successfully sent ?

Comment: @yakiang because when i hardcode ?item='something'&item2='something', it's displaying on php

Comment: @user2799617: please do not be rude to other community members here. I have reported your earlier comment to a moderator. If you believe a question to be poor, then downvote it if you wish, but remain civil - beginners have to start somewhere.

Comment: @RainbowHat: I suspect your earlier comment has been removed by a moderator. If someone is rude to you here, my advice is to flag it as "unconstructive" or "offensive", and do not otherwise respond. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.python-requests.org/

Solution : Use the correct library.